# How to specify a variable or dictionary with a string?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

i want to create an object of `My_Class` and want to tell it with a string what dictionary to get. Is there a better way than to do it with `if`?

```
object_dictionary = {
    "car" : "some_car",
    "house" : "some_house",
    "animal" : "some_animal"
}

class My_Class:
    def __init__(self, string):
        if string == "object_dictionary":
            self.dictionary = object_dictionary

obj = My_Class("object_dictionary")
```

If I want to choose between more dictionaries this will be inconvenient. How can I do this?

```
object_dictionary = {
    "car" : "some_car",
    "house" : "some_house",
    "animal" : "some_animal"
}

class My_Class:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.dictionary = string

obj = My_Class("object_dictionary")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  dict of dicts. See below

```
dicts = {
    "this_dictionary": {
        "car": "some_car",
        "house": "some_house",
        "animal": "some_animal"
    },
    "that_dictionary": {
        "12": "ttt"
    }
}



class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, dict_name):
        self.dictionary = dicts.get(dict_name, {})


obj = MyClass("that_dictionary")
```

Comment: But this will change the original dictionary. What if the dictionary is set by a user such that you cannot change it by making a dict of dicts?

Comment: @PCM that is a good question. Lets hear the OP and understand if that can work for him.

Comment: im sorry, it says I need more reputation to upvote

Comment: @Johannes No problem.. wait until you will have enough reputation.